# QGIS - advanced Atlas settings - display attributes combined by parcel

Tags: qgis, filter, layouts, atlas

I have a polygon containing information about a planned usage (construcion-roads or construction sites) which were intersected with the parcel- and owner-information. So the attribute-table contains parcelinformation, ownerinformation and usageinformation. if a parcel is owned by 2 owners it has two overlapping identical polygones, and if it has also a planned construction road, aswell as a construtcion site, that  means, 4 identical polygons exist for each owner with each type of usage.

I've set up an Atlas to automate the export by choosing the page name "parcelnumber", sorting by "owner" and set the style of the layer rule based to
`"usage" = 'construction-site' AND @atlas_featureid = $id` and because there is a second usage to `"usage" = 'construction-road' AND @atlas_featureid = $id` and ELSE to transparent 15%. This is what it looks like:

[image: example screenshot]

my question is: if possible, how can I set up the Atlas in a way, to display both/all usagetypes per owner which are within one parcel at the same time in the same printsheet? at the moment the Atlas-function is creating one plot for each polygon.

Comment: To clarify, in the above example there would be tow separate map atlas pages;
one for usage 'construction-site' and one for usage 'Bconstruction-road'?

Comment: the above example displays the status quo. the highlighted geometry shows the construction-road. In the same parcel, however, there is still a construction-site geometry. But in the actual atlas settings I get separate printed maps for each usage-type. Goal would be, to set the atlas, to bring construction-roads and sonstruction-sites together per parcel, per owner in one printed page, and leave the other surrounding polygons transparent...

Comment: Ah ok, can you add an image of what the 'construction-road' section looks like.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you can combine filtering and layout in your layer so each polygon is "iluminated" for each atlas page. Here is an example I've reproduced from your description.

The layer is composed by 4 features (two overlapping polygons and two overlapping road). I named the parcel the same, but I think that for this example it doesn't matter.

[image]

Then I went to the atlas layout and set it up, sorting by owner and creating a page name. Then I activated the atlas:

[image]

With atlas activated it will be much easier to set it up now the layout of the layer. Set it to based on rules and first set the filter based in "owner"  with this code `"owner" = attribute(@atlas_feature, 'owner')`. With this you should get rid of the overlapping polygons correspondent to the other owners.

[image]

To make the layer pop up dependent on "construction" or "road" you can add new rules within this layout to change the opacity or the outside line. In this case I've changed the opacity to 75/25 if in correspondence with the atlas page or not. To acces here you have to go the the expression symbol on the right. If the expression is well written it will be illuminated in yellow.

[image]

Finally, I did the same in the outline section, changing it between widths of 1/0.2, like here:

[image]

With this, in a simple way you can have one layer and several layouts, depending on the atlas feature you are currently in:

[image]

[Here you have the QGIS project if you want to check it out](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/141OI5mMMG9USobnJEE9KSIYW-Z8U41EJ?usp=sharing). I hope I understood well your issue, otherwise, this can work as a tutorial XD.